# Appending to $PATH through a script

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to append a folder to my PATH through a script, but this does not change the PATH after execution. If I add the same lines in my .bash_profile, sure enough the PATH has the correct folder in it.

Is there a certain rule that the PATH environment variable can only be changed through .bash_profile?

```
#!/bin/bash
# add anaconda to path
if [ -d $HOME/anaconda3/bin ] ; then
     echo "Changing python to 3.5 :"
     python --version
     PATH="$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin"
     python --version
fi
```

The reason I want to do this is to sometimes use python v2.7 (default) and sometimes use python v3.5 (would be made default by the script).
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the environment of the current process by executing a child process. In order for the change to `PATH` to persist, you must source your script instead of executing it.

```
> source enableAnaconda
```

If you define a function instead in your `.bash_profile`, the function will be defined in every `bash` session and can be called as a distinct command.

```
enableAnaconda () {
  if [ -d "$HOME/anaconda3/bin" ] ; then
    echo "Changing python to 3.5 :"
    PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    python --version
  fi
}
```

You need to *prepend* the new directory to your `PATH`, as `python` will be looked for in the path directories from the beginning.

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! Also thanks for the extra information, I wasn't aware of this : )